# Multiple Sinatra apps using rack-mount

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a question regarding using rack-mount with Sinatra. I've got two classic-style Sinatra apps. Let's call one App defined in app.rb and the other API defined in api.rb.

I would like it so that api.rb handles all routes beginning with '/api' and app.rb handles all other requests including the root ('/').

How would I set this up with rack-mount? Or is there a better solution than that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you'll prefer Rack::URLMap - it will probably look something like this:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => App.new, 
                     "/api" => Api.new)
```

That should go in your `config.ru` file.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, although I had to change the brackets to parentheses.

Comment: One problem I've noticed with this, though, is that stuff in say "/images", "/javascripts", etc. are being processed thru Sinatra which isn't working. How can I get around that? I'm noticing this only using the 'thin' server.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the problem you have there?

Comment: I wound up using this to solve my problem:

    use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/images", "/javascripts", "/stylesheets"], :root => "public"

Comment: You can also add `set :static, true` to your Sinatra app.

Comment: Sorry, you'll also need to `set :public, <your public dir>`.  [Sinatra Config](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) has all the details for this.

Comment: Setting `:public, <my public dir>` and `enable :static` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and I am not very familiar with Rack. I could not figure out what to do based on the answers above. My final solution was to have the following in `config.ru`.

This works perfectly for me.

```
# Main Ramaze site
map "/" do

    Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
    Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

    require ::File.expand_path('../app', __FILE__)

    Ramaze.start(:root => __DIR__, :started => true)
    run Ramaze

end

# Sinatra & Grape API
map "/api" do

    use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images", "/javascripts"], :root => "public"
    use Rack::Session::Cookie

    run Rack::Cascade.new([
        MySinatraApp::Application,
        MySinatraApp::API])

end
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. File config.ru executed in Rack::Builder namespace, which provides DSL to iteratively construct Rack applications, and Rack automatically builds Rack::URLMap.

Answer (score 9):

In `config.ru` you could also take advantage of Sinatra's middleware feature.  If you have several Sinatra apps, each with its own routes, and want to run them simultaneously, you can arrange them in the order you want them found, e.g.

```
# config.ru
...
use MyAppA
use MyAppB
use MyAppC
run MyAppD
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once and so I came up with this template: [sinatra-rspec-bundler-template](https://github.com/daddz/sinatra-rspec-bundler-template) which is layed out for multiple apps.

It may have more features than you need but it should help you when you need something "a bit more" complex.