# How to mount a Sinatra application inside another Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to write a Sinatra application that groups components together (sort of like controllers). So for the "blog" related things, I want an app called `Blog` mounted at `/blog`. All of the routes contained in the `Blog` app would be relative to its mounted path, so I could simply define an `index` route without having to specify the mount path in the route.

I originally handled this by using a config.ru file and `map`ing the routes to the different apps. The problem with this that I ran into, was that I was using various sinatra gems/extensions/helpers that needed to be included in all of the apps, so there was a lot of duplicate code.

How can I mount one sinatra app inside of another so that the routes defined in the app are relative to where the app is mounted? If this is not possible out-of-the-box, can you show a code sample of how this could be done?

Here's a simplified example of what it might look like:

```
class App
  mount Blog, at: '/blog'
  mount Foo, at: '/bar'
end

class Blog
  get '/' do
    # index action
  end
end

class Foo
  get '/' do
    # index action
  end
end
```

Comment: I was looking for the same approach but it seems that we can't do that on Sinatra. But I found a microframework who does that and its really great.
Take a look [into cuba](https://github.com/soveran/cuba#composition). It's not a perfect solution but your next project you can move on Cuba.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want (in code)?

Comment: @Jeffrey I've added a pseudo code example

Comment: As far as I know every sinatra app has a hash of routes. when you implement your `mount` method, make it iterate over the app's routes and add the prefix to the path. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Here's an example of using `Rack::URLMap` in case I decide to use this in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496433/multiple-sinatra-apps-using-rack-mount?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699791/335847 which has some ideas about namespacing.

Personally, I would use the config.ru with mapped routes. If you're really in that space between "should this be a separate app or is it just helpful to organize it like this" it allows that, and then later you can still farm off one of the apps on its own without changing the code (or only a little). If you're finding that there's a lot of duplicated set up code, I'd do something like this:

```
# base_controller.rb

require 'sinatra/base'
require "haml"
# now come some shameless plugs for extensions I maintain :)
require "sinatra/partial"
require "sinatra/exstatic_assets"

module MyAmazingApp
  class BaseController < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::Partial
    register Sinatra::Exstatic

  end

  class Blog < BaseController
    # this gets all the stuff already registered.
  end

  class Foo < BaseController
    # this does too!
  end
end

# config.ru

# this is just me being lazy
# it'd add in the /base_controller route too, so you
# may want to change it slightly :)
MyAmazingApp.constants.each do |const|
  map "/#{const.name.downcase}" do
    run const
  end
end
```

Here's a quote from [Sinatra Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019664.do):

> Not only settings, but every aspect of a Sinatra class will be inherited by its subclasses. This includes defined routes, all the error handlers, **extensions**, middleware, and so on.

It has some good examples of using this technique (and others). Since I'm in shameless plug mode I recommend it, even though I've nothing to do with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same problems.

I found that whatever `inclued  extend register` or  rack middleware style `use` had problems.

You can use Ruby to solve this problems like that:

```rb
require "sinatra"

class App < Sinatra::Base

  class << self
    def define_routes(&block)
      class_eval(&block)
    end
  end

end

App.define_routes do 

  get "/hello"
    "hello world"
  end
end
```