# Build routes on top of a common base route?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have a common base path; say: `get /base` where I need to have basic auth performed and working for all sub calls under that path. Say: `get /base/foo` and `get /base/bar`.

Looking at http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers suggests I should be able to do this with the use of helpers. I was looking at the `pass` helper and use of `call` under triggering a new route in the documentation. But, another suggestion I read was using dynamic routing using regexes IE `%r{/base/?:(path)?}` or some such. So what about:

```
def '/base'
    # do some funky basic auth stuff here
    # to work with all request to this common
    # base path?
    pass
end

def %r{/base/?(path)?} do |path|
    case path
        when 'foo'
            # do something.
        when 'bar'
            # do something else.
    end

    # some kind of redirection or template rendering here:
    erb :template
end
```

Has anyone dealt with this kind of thing before? I'm trying to keep it DRY. Of course, I'm not sure the given example would be the best in preserving params.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this (these aren't in any order, they're all good):

#### Namespaces with a before block and a helper

http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-contrib/1.3.2/Sinatra/Namespace

```
require 'sinatra/namespace'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace

  namespace "/base" do
    helpers do # this helper is now namespaced too
      def authenticate!
      # funky auth stuff
      # but no need for `pass`
      end
    end

    before do
      authenticate!
    end
  
    get "/anything" do
    end

    get "/you" do
    end

    get "/like/here" do
    end
  end
```

#### Namespace with a condition

```
require 'sinatra/namespace'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace

  set(:auth) do |*roles|   # <- notice the splat here
    condition do
      unless logged_in? && roles.any? {|role| current_user.in_role? role }
        redirect "/login/", 303
      end
    end
  end

  namespace "/base", :auth => [:user] do
    # routes…
  end

  namespace "/admin", :auth => [:admin] do
    # routes…
  end
```

#### Helpers and a before filter

```
helpers do
  def authenticate!
    # funky auth stuff
    # but no need for `pass`
  end
end

before '/base/*' do
  authenticate!
end
```

#### mapped Apps

```
class MyBase < Sinatra::Base
  helpers do
    def authenticate!
      # funky auth stuff
      # but no need for `pass`
    end
  end

  before do
    authenticate!
  end

  get "/" do
  end
  get "/another" do
  end
end

# in rackup file

map "/" do
  run App1
end
map "/base" do
  # every route in MyBase will now be accessed by prepending "/base"
  # e.g. "/base/" and "/base/another"
  run MyBase
end
#…
```

I'm not sure about the need to DRY up routes using a case statement. If the routes each do something different then I'd just write them out separately as it's a lot clearer and you're duplicating the work Sinatra does in matching routes.

Comment: it's not even necessary to use a modular app, a classic will do too to keep it even more simple.

Comment: @three I used a modular because the mapping example uses it and I wanted to keep the examples consistent.

Comment: @three Out of curiosity, how would you do it using the classic method?

Comment: @Jim for every example except for the mapping, just remove the class statements and `register` statements and everything should just work. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions-wild.html.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `before` filters:

```
before '/base/?*' do
    @foo = 'bar'
end
```