# Testing a rack service that relies on another rack service

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack

I am re-factoring a medium-sized web application which has many unit tests and acceptance tests written using RSpec. My main goal is to clean up code for a microservice that runs as a separate rack application in production. The current test suite uses process management to start and stop the microservice, which is causing problems with test performance and complicating how the test environment manages test fixture data.

There are hundreds of tests that rely on the correct behaviour of the microservice, which means on this re-factoring pass I will not get the opportunity to fully mock out or fake the microservice itself. But I would really like to remove all the separate process-handling and the associated costs. This is now feasible since I am adding unit tests for the microservice itself, and we have a separate smoke and integration test infrastructure which already runs with the microservice handled as a separate rack-based service.

I have created a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem. It is in multiple small files, fully functional and includes tests. Apologies for the overall length, but I think it is unavoidable because my question is about how to combine these multiple components.

### Microservice

**microservice/app.rb**

```
require "grape"

class Microservice < Grape::API
  format      :json
  get '/main' do
    { :message => "Hello World!" }
  end
end
```

**microservice/config.ru**

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "app")
run Microservice
```

**microservice/spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require_relative '../app.rb'

require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

def app
  Microservice
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

**microservice/spec/microservice_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe Microservice do
  describe "GET /main" do
    it "responds with correct JSON" do
      get "/main"
      expect( last_response ).to be_ok
      data = JSON.parse( last_response.body )
      expect( data ).to be == { "message" => "Hello World!" }
    end
  end
end
```

### Main Web Application

**webapp/app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'httparty'

# This stands in for more complex config we have in reality
$microservice_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/'

get '/main' do
  # Calls a microservice . . . (annoyingly the service uses the same route name)
  response = HTTParty.get( $microservice_url + "main" )
  data = JSON.parse( response.body )
  "#{data['message']}\n"
end
```

**webapp/spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require_relative '../app.rb'

require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

# Is there something I can do here to load the
# microservice without launching it in a new process, and route
# the HTTParty.get in the main app to it?

$microservice_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/'
```

**webapp/spec/webapp_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe "Main web app" do
  describe "GET /main" do
    it "responds with correct text" do
      get "/main"
      expect( last_response ).to be_ok
      expect( last_response.body ).to include "Hello World!"
    end
  end
end
```

I can run the microservice test easily:

```
rspec -f d -c microservice/spec/microservice_spec.rb
```

But to run the webapp test, I first need to start up the microservice where the test expects to find it:

```
rackup -p 8888
```

(Different process)

```
rspec -f d -c webapp/spec/webapp_spec.rb
```

I think I can mount the microservice inside the application, from viewing questions like [How to mount a Sinatra application inside another Sinatra app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496780/how-to-mount-a-sinatra-application-inside-another-sinatra-app) but this seems geared to joining applications in a production environment, I need them to be separate there, joined only in unit tests where the helper enables it, and so far am at a complete loss on how I tell HTTParty (or any replacememt which could do what I want here) to connect.

---

Here's how I might stub the single call in the example (at end of **webapp/spec/spec_helper.rb**) - is there a way to route this to an in-process mount of the microservice instead?

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
include WebMock::API
stub_request( :any, /:8888\// ).to_return( :body => '{ "message":"Hello World!"}' )
```

Comment: What about recording the actual network traffic with [VCR](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs)? Once the traffic is recorded, your tests would run without touching the microservice (so you don't have to start it).

Comment: @Stefan: I think that would just become the mother of all fixtures, very hard to manage, very brittle. It could though be a useful way to start the mocking/stubbing process in future (i.e. if I had time to process and allocate each small network interaction to its test)

Comment: @Stefan: I should also say thank you for the link to VCR - I can see some other places in the main application where it could be very useful.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for a way to start and stop your microservice automatically when running the tests?

Comment: @Stefan: Sort of. I already know how to do that as a separate process and how to run `webmock` whilst allowing local connections. That is what the current tests do. But there is a lot of overhead for running it that way. I want to start the microservice in the same `rack/test` environment, and run everything in a single process, simply sending microservice requests to the correct route handler via the Rack interface, same as `rack/test` already does to the unit under test.

Comment: Maybe modify the title to start with "Testing a rack service that relies on another rack service..." for future people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebMock provides [routing to a Rack response](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#rack-responses), so package `microservice` so it's available to `webapp` and then you can:

```
require 'microservice'
stub_request( :any, /:8888\// ).to_rack( Microservice )
```

Comment: I think that's it! Definitely works on my example in any case. I was just looking too deep for this in the wrong places. Many thanks.

Comment: If it's any consolation my response was a bit longer until I got to the end and had to look up the final webmock stub (which I haven't used extensively) then noticed it did all the leg work for you! Basically, `Rack::Test` allows the same type of thing if you don't rely on the `app` method Mixin: `Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(Microservice)).get( '/main' ).body`