# how do I host a bunch of service-based Sinatra apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, sinatra

I know how to build little Sinatra apps in a service oriented way because of the books I am reading. What I am not clear about is how to host them. If each one is its own self-contained app, how to I host them together? I am coming from a Rails mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend to host each app it self when they not from the same project.

But if belong together you can use `URLMap`

```
# config.ru    
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => App.new, 
                     "/api" => Api.new)
```

Or you can use Sinatra's middleware feature

```
# config.ru
...
use MyAppA
use MyAppB
use MyAppC
run MyAppD
```

Source: [Multiple Sinatra apps using rack-mount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6496433/1279355)